# A TraceListener, which throws an exception on a failed assertion

Tags: c#, .net, review, design-by-contract, trace-listener

My problem with `DefaultTraceListener` (which is the only trace listener, if not overridden in app.config) is that, if `AssertUiEnabled` is `false` (i.e. in ASP.NET) it writes a message as `OutputDebugString` on failed assertions (calls to `Trace.Assert(false)`), **but continues the execution**.

So I'm using the following sub-class of `TraceListener`, which instead throws an exception. I activate it using

```
TraceListenerWhichThrowsExceptionOnFail.InsertAsFirstTraceListener(Trace.Listeners);
```

in `Application_Init`.

Now, in the `Application_Error` event I can log the exception (as any exception) with the full stack trace, including the call of `Trace.Assert(false)`.

```
public class TraceListenerWhichThrowsExceptionOnFail : TraceListener
{
    public static void InsertAsFirstTraceListener(TraceListenerCollection traceListeners)
    {
        traceListeners.Insert(0, new TraceListenerWhichThrowsExceptionOnFail());
    }

    public override void Fail(string message, string detailMessage)
    {
        message = string.IsNullOrEmpty(detailMessage) ? message : message + ", Detail message: " + detailMessage;

        throw new ApplicationException("Trace assertion failed" + 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) ? "" : ": " + message) + ".");
    }

     public override void Write(string message)
     {
        // NOP
     }

     public override void WriteLine(string message)
     {
        // NOP
     }
}
```

Now my question: Does anyone see a problem with this approach?

Comment: Looks like question is more appropriate for code review site

Answer (score 0):

I'd say exception in Trace.Assert is bad idea (not looking at your code).

Trace.XXXX methods generally used to trace stuff. It would be very surprising to future readers (including you) to learn that `Trace.Assert` actually throws exception.

It is even more surprising to see Trace.Assert (or even Fail) throwing exception. Purpose of Assert is to help identify issues in advance, not to kill application.

I'd recommend to come up with your custom method that clearly shows its behavior in the name instead of coming up with unexpected behavior of existing methods.

Comment: `Trace.Assert` does not throw an exception. `Trace.Assert(false)` (which expresses that something went wrong) does.

Comment: @meepgoose, not sure what you are commenting about. I read your question as "is it ok to make particular method to behave in a way most people do not expect (i.e. throw exception when normal behavior is never throw irrespective of arguments)" and answered this way. My understanding of expected behavior very well could be wrong, so check with people you know/work with if anyone expects behavior you've implemented.

Comment: I'm with moop on this one. While `Trace.XXX` methods are indeed generally meant to trace stuff, I could just as easily make the argument that `XXX.Assert` methods are generally meant to stop the execution of your program due to some invariant violation in your logic. Moreover, I would also make the claim that `Trace.Assert` is the release-mode equivalent of `Debug.Assert`. MSDN itself says: *Use the Trace.Assert method if you want to do assertions in release builds. The Debug.Assert method works only in debug builds*. Under this premise it makes more sense for `Trace.Assert` to throw than log.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

I'm not sure this would be useful in an ASP.NET scenario. During debugging, you want assertions to behave normally. Throwing exceptions would probably be a bit confusing. And in production, you would use release builds, so that the `Trace.Assert` statements don't do anything anyway.

However, we use a similar technique for unit tests. You really don't want to have your build server hanging showing an "Assertion Failed" message box. Instead, you want your assertions to cause the tests to fail. So we use an App.config file for our unit tests (and only for hose!), that installs a trace listener that is similar to yours.

Comment: The default "Release" configuration (which I didn't change) enables the `TRACE` condition. What you mean is `DEBUG` condition (only enabled in the "Debug" configuration).

Answer (score -1):

Throwing an exception in Fail() could lead to:
1. the call stack will be confusing, since the exception is not thrown near where the condition failed.

Generally you should throw exception near where the condition fails.